# Adding div before selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs one after the other.

```
<div class="betweenable">some content</div>
<div class="betweenable">other content</div>
<div class="betweenable">yet another</div>
```

When I click the last div, I want to insert the text `new content` in a div before it, so the final result will be

```
<div class="betweenable">some content</div>
<div class="betweenable">other content</div>
<div class="betweenable">new content</div>
<div class="betweenable">yet another</div>
```

I tried `append` but it's adding the new markup **inside** the select div *at the top*. I want it inserted *outside* the selected div and right before it. What should I use instead of this line

```
var newmarkup = '<div class="betweenable">new content</div>';
$(this).prepend();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$('.betweenable').click(function(){
   var newmarkup = '<div class="betweenable">new content</div>';
   $(this).before(newmarkup);
});
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/C4XyH/

Comment: And if you want to be able to click on the inserted div as well, just change the `.click` function to a `.live('click', function(){...})`

Comment: didn't the selector should be  $('.betweenable:last') ? because he wanted to click on the last div.

Comment: From what I understand, he wants it to work on all. The reference to last was just as an example so we have a usecase.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.before` here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F8C8y/2/)**